# relation between the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Define $l_a : F(a) → F(a) $ by  $ l_a(x)=ax$, when $[F(a):F]=n$ .

show that the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$ is the same as the minimum polynomial of $l_a$ as defined in linear algebra.

this is what i've done to prove :

the associated matrix of $l_a$ is a $n*n$ matrix (because $F(a)$ is a $n$ dimensional space) with $"a"$ on all the main diagonal entries & zero everywhere else, so the characteristic polynomial of $l_a$ is $(a-\lambda)^n$,that is a monic polynomial with degree $n$ and with $a$ as a root.

and because we have $[F(a):F]=n$,so the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$ has degree $n$.

so  the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$ is the same as the characteristic polynomial of $l_a$.

is there any mistake?
is it a complete proof?

thank you.

Comment: The associated matrix is not diagonal. You can't even begin to talk about the associated matrix until you have chosen a basis for $F(a)$ as a vector space over $F$, so that's your first order of business.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  can you please give me a hint to make a new proof?

Comment: I already did. Read what I wrote, and do what I suggested.

Comment: is ${1,a,...,a^(n-1)}$ a good basis?next step?

Comment: Yes, that's a good basis. Now, find the matrix representing $l_a$ with respect to that basis.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** if we take the basis $\{1,a,\dots,a^{n-1}\}$. 
Suppose furthermore that $a^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k a^k$.
Then the matrix of this transformation with respect to the basis is
$$
T_{\ell} =  \pmatrix{&&&&c_0\\1&&&&c_1\\&1&&&\vdots \\&&\ddots\\&&&1&c_{n-1}}
$$
Now, what is the characteristic/minimal polynomial of this linear transformation?  Perhaps this matrix looks [familiar?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)